# Adding "Remember Me" in custom login

Tags: php, ajax, login, wp-login-form

im currently using an ajax login i found here:
http://wpsites.org/wordpress-ajax-login-and-register-without-a-plugin-10835/

Everything works perfectly fine. However i'd like to add a "REMEMBER ME" checkbox/feature but since i don't really code and i'm just modifying a theme that i bought maybe someone could help me out. I just need the "Remember Me" feature on it?

Maybe someone could help me out, i would really appreciate it. Thanks

```
function pt_login_register_modal() {

        // only show the registration/login form to non-logged-in members
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){ 
?>
        <div class="modal fade pt-user-modal" id="pt-user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" data-active-tab="">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <?php

                            if( get_option('users_can_register') ){ ?>

                                <!-- Register form -->
                                <div class="pt-register">

                                    <h3><?php printf( __('Join %s', 'ptheme'), get_bloginfo('name') ); ?></h3>
                                    <hr>

                                    <form id="pt_registration_form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="POST">

                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <label><?php _e('Username', 'ptheme'); ?></label>
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_login" type="text"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <label for="pt_user_email"><?php _e('Email', 'ptheme'); ?></label>
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_email" id="pt_user_email" type="email"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pt_register_member"/>
                                            <button class="btn btn-theme btn-lg" data-loading-text="<?php _e('Loading...', 'ptheme') ?>" type="submit"><?php _e('Sign up', 'ptheme'); ?></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'register-security' ); ?>
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="pt-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Login form -->
                                <div class="pt-login">

                                    <h3><?php printf( __('Login to %s', 'ptheme'), get_bloginfo('name') ); ?></h3>
                                    <hr>

                                    <form id="pt_login_form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="post">

                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <label><?php _e('Username', 'ptheme') ?></label>
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_login" type="text"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <label for="pt_user_pass"><?php _e('Password', 'ptheme')?></label>
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_pass" id="pt_user_pass" type="password"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pt_login_member"/>
                                            <button class="btn btn-theme btn-lg" data-loading-text="<?php _e('Loading...', 'ptheme') ?>" type="submit"><?php _e('Login', 'ptheme'); ?></button> <a class="alignright" href="#pt-reset-password"><?php _e('Lost Password?', 'ptheme') ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'login-security' ); ?>
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="pt-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Lost Password form -->
                                <div class="pt-reset-password">

                                    <h3><?php _e('Reset Password', 'ptheme'); ?></h3>
                                    <p>Enter the username or e-mail you used in your profile. A password reset link will be sent to you by email.</p>
                                    <hr>

                                    <form id="pt_reset_password_form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="post">
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <label for="pt_user_or_email"><?php _e('Username or E-mail', 'ptheme') ?></label>
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg required" name="pt_user_or_email" id="pt_user_or_email" type="text"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pt_reset_password"/>
                                            <button class="btn btn-theme btn-lg" data-loading-text="<?php _e('Loading...', 'ptheme') ?>" type="submit"><?php _e('Get new password', 'ptheme'); ?></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'password-security' ); ?>
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="pt-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="pt-loading">
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i><br><?php _e('Loading...', 'ptheme') ?></p>
                                </div><?php

                            } else {
                                echo '<h3>'.__('Login access is disabled', 'ptheme').'</h3>';
                            } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                            <span class="pt-register-footer"><?php _e('Don\'t have an account?', 'ptheme'); ?> <a href="#pt-register"><?php _e('Sign Up', 'ptheme'); ?></a></span>
                            <span class="pt-login-footer"><?php _e('Already have an account?', 'ptheme'); ?> <a href="#pt-login"><?php _e('Login', 'ptheme'); ?></a></span>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'pt_login_register_modal');




#   
#   AJAX FUNCTION
#   ========================================================================================
#   These function handle the submitted data from the login/register modal forms
#   ========================================================================================
#       

// LOGIN
function pt_login_member(){

        // Get variables
        $user_login     = $_POST['pt_user_login'];  
        $user_pass      = $_POST['pt_user_pass'];


        // Check CSRF token
        if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'login-security', false) ){
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
        }

        // Check if input variables are empty
        elseif( empty($user_login) || empty($user_pass) ){
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
        } else { // Now we can insert this account

            $user = wp_signon( array('user_login' => $user_login, 'user_password' => $user_pass), false );

            if( is_wp_error($user) ){
                echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$user->get_error_message().'</div>'));
            } else{
                echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-success">'.__('Login successful, reloading page...', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
            }
        }

        die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pt_login_member', 'pt_login_member');



// REGISTER
function pt_register_member(){

        // Get variables
        $user_login = $_POST['pt_user_login'];  
        $user_email = $_POST['pt_user_email'];

        // Check CSRF token
        if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'register-security', false) ){
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
            die();
        }

        // Check if input variables are empty
        elseif( empty($user_login) || empty($user_email) ){
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
            die();
        }

        $errors = register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);  

        if( is_wp_error($errors) ){

            $registration_error_messages = $errors->errors;

            $display_errors = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';

                foreach($registration_error_messages as $error){
                    $display_errors .= '<p>'.$error[0].'</p>';
                }

            $display_errors .= '</div>';

            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => $display_errors));

        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-success">'.__( 'Registration complete. Please check your e-mail.', 'ptheme').'</p>'));
        }


        die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pt_register_member', 'pt_register_member');


// RESET PASSWORD
function pt_reset_password(){


        // Get variables
        $username_or_email = $_POST['pt_user_or_email'];

        // Check CSRF token
        if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'password-security', false) ){
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
        }       

        // Check if input variables are empty
        elseif( empty($username_or_email) ){
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'ptheme').'</div>'));
        } else {

            $username = is_email($username_or_email) ? sanitize_email($username_or_email) : sanitize_user($username_or_email);

            $user_forgotten = pt_lostPassword_retrieve($username);

            if( is_wp_error($user_forgotten) ){

                $lostpass_error_messages = $user_forgotten->errors;

                $display_errors = '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
                foreach($lostpass_error_messages as $error){
                    $display_errors .= '<p>'.$error[0].'</p>';
                }
                $display_errors .= '</div>';

                echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => $display_errors));
            }else{
                echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message' => '<p class="alert alert-success">'.__('Password Reset. Please check your email.', 'ptheme').'</p>'));
            }
        }

        die();
}   
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pt_reset_password', 'pt_reset_password');


function pt_lostPassword_retrieve( $user_data ) {

        global $wpdb, $current_site, $wp_hasher;

        $errors = new WP_Error();

        if( empty($user_data) ){
            $errors->add( 'empty_username', __( 'Please enter a username or e-mail address.', 'ptheme' ) );
        } elseif( strpos($user_data, '@') ){
            $user_data = get_user_by( 'email', trim( $user_data ) );
            if( empty($user_data)){
                $errors->add( 'invalid_email', __( 'There is no user registered with that email address.', 'ptheme'  ) );
            }
        } else {
            $login = trim( $user_data );
            $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);
        }

        if( $errors->get_error_code() ){
            return $errors;
        }

        if( !$user_data ){
            $errors->add('invalidcombo', __('Invalid username or e-mail.', 'ptheme'));
            return $errors;
        }

        $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
        $user_email = $user_data->user_email;

        do_action('retrieve_password', $user_login);

        $allow = apply_filters('allow_password_reset', true, $user_data->ID);

        if( !$allow ){
            return new WP_Error( 'no_password_reset', __( 'Password reset is not allowed for this user', 'ptheme' ) );
        } elseif ( is_wp_error($allow) ){
            return $allow;
        }

        $key = wp_generate_password(20, false);

        do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);

        if(empty($wp_hasher)){
            require_once ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';
            $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
        }

        $hashed = $wp_hasher->HashPassword($key);

        $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $hashed), array('user_login' => $user_login));

        $message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:', 'ptheme' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s', 'ptheme' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.', 'ptheme' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:', 'ptheme' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= '<' . network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' ) . ">\r\n\r\n";

        if ( is_multisite() ) {
            $blogname = $GLOBALS['current_site']->site_name;
        } else {
            $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES );
        }

        $title   = sprintf( __( '[%s] Password Reset', 'ptheme' ), $blogname );
        $title   = apply_filters( 'retrieve_password_title', $title );
        $message = apply_filters( 'retrieve_password_message', $message, $key );

        if ( $message && ! wp_mail( $user_email, $title, $message ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'noemail', __( 'The e-mail could not be sent.<br />Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.', 'ptheme' ) );

            return $errors;

            wp_die();
        }

        return true;
}

function ajax_login_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'user-login', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-register/user-login.css', array(), null );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-register/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-login-register-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-register/user-login.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_localize_script('ajax-login-register-script', 'ptajax', array( 
                    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_login_scripts' );

/**
 * Automatically add a Login link to Primary Menu
 */
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'pt_login_link_to_menu', 10, 2 );
function pt_login_link_to_menu ( $items, $args ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == apply_filters('login_menu_location', 'primary') ) {
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item login-link"><a href="#pt-login">'.__( 'Login/Register', 'ptheme' ).'</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

insert this in form:

```
<p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> Remember Me</label></p>
```

In backend, like this:

```
$credentials['user_login'] = $_POST['log'];
$credentials['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];
$credentials['remember'] = $_POST['rememberme'];
.....  wp_signon($credentials)   ....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time sir. I really appreciate it! 
However, im not really a coder so i hope you could make a working code just for the remember me feature which i can simply insert in the php codes above and will match it codes? It would really help a lot..

Btw, it is an ajax validated login form.(modal). Thanks!